Integrating @entryscape/rdforms into an Angular project
I'm currently working on an Angular project and trying to integrate @entryscape/rdforms to handle RDF-based forms. However, I'm facing some difficulties understanding how to use it properly in my project. I've followed the available documentation, but I'm still getting compilation errors.
I've installed @entryscape/rdforms into my Angular project using npm.
npm i @entryscape/rdforms

Despite this, I'm still getting the following error during compilation:
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@entryscape/rdforms'.

I'm a bit lost on how to resolve this issue. Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong with my configuration or what I could do to properly integrate @entryscape/rdforms into my Angular project?
Additionally, I'm curious if there are any other libraries or frameworks available for manipulating RDF/JSON-LD data in an Angular environment. If anyone has experience with alternatives to @entryscape/rdforms or can recommend another library for handling RDF/JSON-LD in Angular, I would greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations.
